# Static strategies or enums for small implementation changes in similar code?

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, strategy-pattern

I have a lot of lines with common code, only 1 line in between differs for some implementations.

Normally I'd chose a strategy pattern for this. But I wonder if a `enum switch()` could be a better approach here. Take the following example. Assume the `Object` can be any object that has mathematical methods like `add(), multiply(), substract()` etc.

With enums I'd go like this:

```
enum Strategy {
    ADD, SUB, MUL;  
}

class DigitUtil {
    public static void update(Object obj, int n, Strategy strat) {
        //some DB stuff

        switch(strat) {
            case ADD: obj.add(n);
                break;
            case SUB: obj.subtract(n);
                break;
            case MUL: obj.multiply(n);
                break;
        }

        //some other DB stuff
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DigitUtil.update(obj, 1, Strategy.ADD); //this adds 1 to the object
DigitUtil.update(obj, 10, Strategy.SUB); //this subtracts 10 from the object
```

Or would you rather pick the strategy pattern for those type of operations?

```
class DigitUtil {
    public static void update(Object obj, int number, Strategy strat) {
        //some DB stuff

        strat.update(obj, number);

        //some other DB stuff
    }

    interface Strategy {
        void update(Object object, int number);
    }

    static class Add implements Strategy {
        @Override
        public oid update(Object obj, int n) {
            obj.add(n);
        }
    }

    static class Subtract implements Strategy {
        @Override
        public oid update(Object obj, int n) {
            obj.subtract(n);
        }
    }

    static class Multiply implements Strategy {
        @Override
        public oid update(Object obj, int n) {
            obj.multiply(n);
        }
    }

    public static final Strategy ADD = new DigitUtil.Add();
    public static final Strategy SUB = new DigitUtil.Subtract();
    public static final Strategy MUL = new DigitUtil.Multiply();
}
```

Usage:

```
DigitUtil.update(obj, 1, DigitUtil.ADD);
DigitUtil.update(obj, 10, DigitUtil.SUB);
```

Is there any benefit for one approach over the other? Which would you chose in which situation?

Comment: I find the first approach a bit cleaner. I also believe that, if your interface will always only have one implementation, then you should reconsider why you have that interface in the first place.

Comment: Just throwing this out there: with enum you can basically do both. Your Strategy enum can have an update method. Then you don't need the switch but at the same time the client must pass an existing constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strategy pattern (which would be *much* more concise if Java had lambdas already) is open to extension by additional strategies while the enum approach is not. As a design decision this essentially comes down to the [*expression problem*](https://www.google.com/search?q=expression+problem).

Choose the enum approach if you have many methods that operate on those enums in different ways, and you perhaps [want a compiler warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797529/how-to-ensure-completeness-in-an-enum-switch-at-compile-time) if you add an enum entry and forget to update one of those methods. Prefer the strategy pattern if you expect to define more operations, perhaps in other modules of the program.

If you only have one method processing the enums/strategies and the set of enums/strategies is unlikely to change then it doesn't matter which you choose. I'd probably go with enums in Java 7 because they are more concise.

Also, remember that enums can have methods, so the enum entries can implement your update method just like the strategies do. Whether to prefer this over a switch statement is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `enum` would be a better approach.

- It will force the programmer to use only one of those methods for
  mathematical operations.
- Personally, using enums looks cleaner to me than creating static classes for the same purpose.
- If it is neededed to add or remove some mathematical operation, then its easier to modify an `enum` instead of making a static nested class implement an interface and then again instantiating it.

Again this is my personal opinion and it may differ from others

Answer (score 2):

This question can start a whole debate. Even if the first approach looks cleaner, I would go for the second approach - I mean the strategy pattern. Using the enums and switches make your code tight coupled - if new operations need to be added then the switch needs more cases. On the other hand, following OOAD and OOP best practices [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) and using the **O** from from [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)([Open/Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) that is) I would go for the Strategy pattern even if this code snippet it looks more complex.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have created an SDK include the `DigitUtil`. Now one of thousand clients need to use this method with a new custom strategy (e.g Division):

In the enum approach, you must upgrade your SDK but using Strategy pattern you do not need to any change.